# Clojurescript: process requests in chunks with core/async channels

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, clojurescript, channel

I have the following scenario:

There's some service I use to retrieve some data passing it my input.

Having some input parameters I need to perform N requests against the aforementioned service, gather outputs and do some CPU-heavy task for each output.

I am trying to achieve this using core/async channels.

Here's my attempt (schematically) which kinda works, but it doesn't behave I would like it to.
Will be grateful for any hints on how to improve it.

```
(defn produce-inputs
  [in-chan inputs]
  (let input-names-seq (map #(:name %) inputs)]
    (doseq [input-name input-names-seq]
      (async/go
        (async/>! in-chan input-name)))))

(defn consume
  [inputs]
  (let [in-chan (async/chan 1)
        out-chan (async/chan 1)]
        (do
          (produce-inputs in-chan inputs)
          (async/go-loop []
                   (let [input-name (async/<! in-chan)]
                     (do
                         (retrieve-resource-from-service input-name 
                                                         ; response handler
                                                         (fn [resp]
                                                           (async/go
                                                             (let [result (:result resp)]
                                                               (async/>! out-chan result)))))
                         (when input-name
                           (recur)))))

     ; read from out-chan and do some heavy work for each entry
     (async/go-loop []
                   (let [result (async/<! out-chan)]
                         (do-some-cpu-heavy-work result))))))

; entry point
(defn run
  [inputs]
  (consume inputs))
```

Is there any way to update it so that at every moment there will be no more than five requests to service (`retrieve-resource-from-service`) active?

If my explanation isn't clear, please ask questions, I will update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create another channel to act as a token bucket for limiting the rate of your requests.

[See this link](https://lispcast.com/token-buckets-in-core-async/) for an example of using a token bucket for per-second rate limiting.

To limit the number of simultaneous requests, you can do something along the lines of:

```
(defn consume [inputs]
  (let [in-chan (async/chan 1)
        out-chan (async/chan 1)
        bucket (async/chan 5)]
    ;; ...
    (dotimes [_ 5] (async/put! bucket :token))
    (async/go-loop []
      (let [input-name (async/<! in-chan)
            token (async/<! bucket)]
        (retrieve-resource-from-service
          input-name 
          ; response handler
          (fn [resp]
            (async/go
              (let [result (:result resp)]
                (async/>! out-chan result)
                (async/>! bucket token)))))
        (when input-name
          (recur))))
    ;; ...
    ))
```

A new channel, `bucket`, is created, and five items are put into it. Before firing a request, we take a token from the bucket, and put it back once the request is completed. If there are no tokens in the `bucket` channel, we have to wait until one of the requests is done.

Note: this is just a sketch of the code, you may have to correct it. In particular, if you have any error handlers in your `retrieve-resource-from-service` function, you should put the token back in case of an error too to avoid eventual deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you. I like this approach, will give it a go and write back.